# Attach categories to a range of values (percentages) and sort?

Tags: r, range, levels

So I have a csv which I have manipulated to give me this table called
[Completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wHZK.png)

```
 dput(Completion)

 structure(list(value = structure(1:16, .Label = c("0%", "100%", "13%", "15%","16%", "24%", "26%", "28%", "33%", "40%", "50%", "53%", "66%", "73%", "75%", "93%"), class = "factor"), All = c(13L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), 
M0 = c(14L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), M1 = c(17L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), M2 = c(21L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), M3 = c(21L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L)), 
.Names = c("value", "All", "M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = 
c("cast_df", "data.frame"), idvars = "value", rdimnames = list(structure(list(value = 
structure(1:16, .Label = c("0%", "100%", "13%", "15%", "16%", "24%", "26%", "28%", "33%", 
"40%", "50%", "53%", "66%", "73%", "75%", "93%"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = "value", row.names = c("0%", "100%", "13%", "15%", "16%", "24%", "26%", "28%", 
"33%", "40%", "50%", "53%", "66%", "73%", "75%", "93%"), class = "data.frame"), 
structure(list(Module = structure(1:5, .Label = c("All", 
"M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Module", row.names = c("All", 
"M0", "M1", "M2", "M3"), class = "data.frame")), .Label = 
c("0-49","50-59","60-69", "70-79",
"80-89", ">90"))
```

This table shows the number of people who completed (value)% of a given module in a course.

What I would like to do is create categories for the values as follows;
Majority(90%-100%), Substantial(75%-89%), Partial(50%-74%), Minimal(1%-49%), and Incomplete(0%) 
I would then like to be able to get a count of all of the instances of this *by module*, like this:

```
              M0     M1     M2     M3     All
Majority       1      2      3      4       5
Substantial    5      4      3      2       1 
Partial        4      3      2      1       5 
Minimal        3      2      1      5       4 
Incomplete     2      1      5      4       3
```

The count of each of the instances would fill up the table.

Is there a way to do this? I have tried making different pivot tables, and attaching levels;

```
comp.rate <- Completion$value
comp.rate <- ordered(comp.rate, levels = c("Majority", "Substantial", "Partial", "Minimal", 
"Incomplete"))
```

I think I don't know how to assign the values I want  to these levels and then, in turn, get R to spit out their occurrences. I have also had problems because the values are in percentage form... and not decimal. I haven't attached my full code, but I can if it is of any use...
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please place the output of `dput(Completion)` here instead of a screenshot so that others can quickly reproduce your example. In addition, can you be more clear about the interpretation of `data.frame` `Completion` -- for instance, the first row (0%) mean for All = 13 and how does that relate to the last row (93%) All = 3?

Comment: Hey! Let me know if the dput is what you meant... The value column is all of the different percentages that participants in this course completed. Your example (0% ; All = 13) means that for the entire course, 13 people completed 0%. For the last row, it means that 3 people completed 93% of the course. Same w/ the modules. In the 5th row for M2, 1 person completed 16% of that module. I would like to put those percentages into ranges, instead of every possible percentage produced. Let me know if I can explain anything else further. This is my first post, so I'm new to asking :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

First you have to transform the percentage column to a numeric one using `gsub`

```
d$value <- as.numeric(gsub("[%]", "", d$value))
```

then you can count all occurences using a condition and `colSums`:

```
#Majority(90%-100%)
colSums(d[ d$value >= 90, ])
value   All    M0    M1    M2    M3 
  193     3    10     6     4     2 

# or Substantial(75%-89%)
colSums(d[ d$value >= 75 & d$value < 89, ])
value   All    M0    M1    M2    M3 
   75     0     0     0     0     2
```

Saving all together in one data.frame:

```
a1 <- colSums(d[ d$value >= 90,])
a2 <- colSums(d[ d$value >= 75 & d$value < 89, ])
result <- data.frame(rbind(a1, a2))
result$value <- c("Majority", "Substantial")
result
         value All M0 M1 M2 M3
a1    Majority   3 10  6  4  2
a2 Substantial   0  0  0  0  2
```